# Assigning CSS ID to Javascript Created Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create Dynamic Content for a HTML page, using JavaScript to create elements based on click events, which would be affected by pre-existing CSS styling.

But I can't seem to hook the new element to it's CSS ID.

```
crestDiv.onclick = function()
{
    //Remove the Elements on Screen
    var element = document.getElementById("crestDiv");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    element = document.getElementById("breakDiv");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    element = document.getElementById("buildDiv");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    element = document.getElementById("surgeDiv");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    element = document.getElementById("wavesIcon");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    //Add the Elements to Screen

    //Create Heading
    var heading = document.createElement("h1");
    heading.id = "crestTitle";
    var node = document.createTextNode("Crest Heading");
    heading.appendChild(node);

    //Attach Heading to existing Element
    element = document.getElementById("contentDiv");
    element.appendChild(heading);
}
```

It works, the heading appears on the screen after all the rest of the content disappears, but it has no CSS styling on it.

You can see I'm trying to use the CSS ID of "crestTitle" to apply to the new Heading, but no matter what styling I put under #crestTitle in my CSS sheet, it doesn't affect the new heading.

Am I making any obvious errors?

Comment: You should use a css class. i.e. `.crestTitle` and `heading.classList.add("crestTitle");`

Comment: What is the CSS? Do you end up having more than one item with the same id? Basic HTML so we can run it?

Comment: Add your html code to the question

Comment: add jsfiddle example wih css code

Comment: Without actually seeing your CSS, it's hard to say.

Comment: Cross check your css file .you could have misspelled the id

Comment: Thanks all, I have checked the CSS, I haven't misspelled the ID, and the CSS is simply 

#crestTitle
{
    font-size: 500%;
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v8g86cpe/

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) including your HTML and CSS as well?
This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nw35g21x/

CSS:

```
#crestDiv{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100px;
  background-color:cyan;
}

#crestTitle{
  color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="contentDiv">
<div id="crestDiv">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var crestDiv = document.getElementById("crestDiv");
crestDiv.onclick = function()
{
    //Remove the Elements on Screen
    var element = document.getElementById("crestDiv");

    //Add the Elements to Screen

    //Create Heading
    var heading = document.createElement("h1");
    heading.id = "crestTitle";
    var node = document.createTextNode("Crest Heading");
    heading.appendChild(node);

    //Attach Heading to existing Element
    element = document.getElementById("contentDiv");
    element.appendChild(heading);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how effective the jsfiddle will be due to the lack of local saved images etc. but here you go 
http://jsfiddle.net/v8g86cpe/

Comment: The style is applied to the element. But you need to change the CSS attribute from 'font-color' to 'color'